# Why does Python say that a function that I have defined isn't defined?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I've been using Python(2.7) for a while now, but just started using classes. It tells me that GameIntro is not defined. I've been trying to fix it, but it doesn't want to work:

```
import random

from Tkinter import *
import time

class win():
root = Tk()

root.wm_title("HauntFall")#Title of window

text1 = Label(root, text = "HAUNTFALL", font = ('MS Serif', 50, 'bold'), fg = "white", bg = "black")
text1.pack()#This one and ^ that one make the big lettered HauntFall.

butt1 = Button(root, text = "PLAY", font = ('MS Serif', 15, 'bold'), fg = 'red', command = GameIntro)
butt1.pack(pady = 3)#These two make the PLAY button.



root.configure(bg='black')#This one sets the background to black.

root.mainloop()#Puts the window in a loop, so it doesn't immediately close.

def GameIntro():
    x = win()
    print "Gj"
    x.text1.configure( font = ('MS Serif', 12, 'bold'),text = "You approach a house abandoned many years ago - though you can hear faint creaking, and various other noises coming from inside it's shadowy depths. You approach the large wooden doors, and stare up at all 3 stories of the horrifing place. The house has always been a mystery, and although you are the curious type, you have been hesitant to go in. You promise yourself not to succumb to your fears, and you pull open the old wooden doors.", wraplength = 500)
    x.butt1.configure( text = 'Continue', font = ('MS Serif', 12, 'bold'))
```

Comment: You need another closing parens in the line `win.butt1.configure(win.root, text = 'Continue', font = ('MS Serif', 12, 'bold') )#<--add this`.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is valid Python code, as there is no indentation after the line `class win():`

Comment: I tried putting GameIntro above the class, but it said that the variables like text1 and butt1 didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function isn't defined until after `mainloop` exits, which means it's not defined while the window exists. You must ahve the `def GameIntro` somewhere before the code that calls the function executes.